# Update Database row with only modified values via PDO through my own API

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

I am creating an API that interacts with an MVC setup (CodeIgniter) that connects to my database via PDO and I am wondering how to best achieve the scenario described below...

Assume the following exists as a row in `Table1`:

```
| Id: 1 | Object: Box | Color: "red" | Length: 1 | Height: 2 | Width: 3 |
```

If I make the following API call (pseudo code):

```
$this->post( 'Table1/update', array('id'=>1, 'color' => "blue") );
```

where it is assumed that the color parameter is updated to "blue", but all other params are to remain the same.

**What process do I go through to update only the color parameter and not the other empty params? [assume that there are many possible parameters, not just 4] **

In my model, do I act like everything is to be updated and have every possible parameter listed with `bindParam` or do I dynamically (via `foreach` loop) iterate through all available parameters to create a PDO statement to update for only those values?  Stated more simply, **how do I write the PDO statement to work with all possible combinations of row updating?**

It seems to me that I have the following two options, but neither of them seems very efficient:

**Use foreach loops to account for only present parameters:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Table1` 
        SET ";
$i = 0;
foreach( $params as $key => $val )
{
    $sql .= '`' . $key . '` = :' . $key;
    if( $i < count( $params )-1 )
    {
        $sql .= ', ';
    }
    $i++;
} 

$sql .= ' WHERE `Id` = :Id';

$stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
foreach( $params as $key => $val )
{
    $stmt->bindParam( ':' . $key, $val, PDO::PARAM_STR );
}
$stmt->bindParam( ':Id', $params['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );*/
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

**Account for all parameters:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE `Table1` 
        SET `Color` = :Color, `Length` = :Length, `Height` = :Height, `Width` = :Width 
        WHERE `Id` =:Id";

$stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql ); 
$stmt->bindParam( ':Color', $params['color'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( ':Length', $params['length'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->bindParam( ':Height', $params['height'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->bindParam( ':Width', $params['width'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->bindParam( ':Id', $params['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

#### Update:

The real crux of the problem is trying to create a single method in the model (called `update`) that the API can interact with and can take any number of parameters and correctly update that row with the given values, meanwhile keeping the other original values unchanged.

Comment: just need to update the particular column and only id and column name would do the job , btw what error and problem are you facing ?

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz I have added an update to make it more clear.  I am essentially trying to write a one-size-fits-all method in the Model that takes all possible combinations of parameters and updates accordingly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think you need to generate the sql on run time by passing the params array the columns you require and that way one global function will do the biding as per the lenght of params array

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt make any sense to include all columns into update statments and bind the values/params to the statement. You can have just color field to be in the set stament and give the id in the where clause.

Comment: I agree, normally I would only update the single item that has been changed, but I am trying to make the API interact with a single method rather than having different methods for each possible case.  I'll update the question to reflect this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering the same problem. My current idea is to pass all field values to the update(...) function, and succeed each value with a boolean $update value. Only if a value TRUE is passed in for this valiable, the corresponding field value will be included in the update statement.

```
function update_ad($id, $title, $update_title, $text, $update_text, $price, $update_price, $visible, $update_visible) {
            if ($update_title) {$this->db->set('title', $title);}
    if ($update_text) {$this->db->set('text', $text);}
    if ($update_price) {$this->db->set('price', $price);}
    if ($update_visible) {$this->db->set('visible', $visible);}

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('ad');
}
```